# Installing proper video drivers

Tags: release-loki, drivers, graphics, amd

I installed Elementary OS Loki today and it doesnt feel smooth at all. It is very laggy. I know for a fact, that once I updated my drives on Ubuntu, which had the same problem, it was really smooth.

I am, however, unable to do that.

I have an AMD Radeon HD 5770 with 512 MB of GDDR5 memory.

I have no idea how to install the proper drivers. I tried many tutorials but none helped.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which driver did you try? There's quite a few details missing here so you'll have to be a bit more descriptive. From a quick scan of [AMD's closed source driver page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux), they ended support for 5000 series cards with 15.04. If it's the open source driver you're looking for, it should have been installed by default with Loki. Can you post the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'`?

Comment: I eventually gave up on this problem, but I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>:~/Downloads$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 7340]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Wrestler [Radeon HD 7340]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```